# Machine learning instance based learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently studying for a Machine Learning exam and I'm stuck on a question in an old exam.

> Question: We use 1/d as a kernel function. What is the prediction of
>   2-nearest neighbour for the data-point (x = 0)?
>
> Figure: [image]

Apparantly the answer is 1.17, but I have no idea how they do this? Googling on that 1/d as a kernel function didn't really help either unfortunately.

It's a beginner class so if possible please keep it simple :)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The two nearest neighbors are at x=1 and x=1.5 (don't let the **y** values fool you).  Using a 1/d weighting, we get

(1/1 + 2/1.5) / 2 = (7/3) / 2 = 7/6

The approximation to 2 decimal places is 1.17

---

Now ... I don't think this is the correct computation; it mis-handles the weightings.  I would use sum of weighted values divided by the sum of the weights:

```
(y1/w1 + y2/w2) / (w1 + w2) 
(1/1 + 2/1.5) / (1/1 + 1/1.5)
(7/3) / (5/3)
7/5
1.40
```